# Update crontab rules without overwriting or duplicating

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scripting, cron

I'm trying to figure out a good solution to the following problem:

- `crontab` contains some default rules (`A,B,C`)
- I have a `setup.sh` script that should append rules from a file `my.cron` to crontab (suppose rules `X,Y,Z`). The resulting rules should be `A,B,C,X,Y,Z`
- I cannot use `crontab my.cron` as it overwrites the existing rules
- I cannot simply append the rules as the `setup.sh` script might be invoked multiple times (which would result in the crontab rules looking like `A,B,C,X,Y,Z,X,Y,Z,X,Y,Z`

Some solutions I could think of are:

- Run a grep command to check whether or not a rule in `my.cron` exists in the crontab or not. If not, append it.
- Create a new user for whom no existing rules are present so that I can overwrite the crontab everytime.

I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to solve this. From what I can tell, there's no way to tell crontab to refer to a set of files to collate the rules (without duplication or overwriting)

Comment: How about appending the rules to my.cron; sort my.cron, and then uniq it?

Comment: Is it possible that your set-up script would ever be modified, for example to fix something in Y ? If so, a solution with `sort -u` would result in running both versions of Y, possibly simultaneously. crontabs are also sequence-dependent: there are environment settings (PATH, SHELL, LOGNAME, MAILTO), and #comments that would lose their context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> From what I can tell, there's no way to tell crontab to refer to a set of files to collate the rules (without duplication or overwriting)/

There is, but not for user crontabs. Use individual files in `/etc/cron.d` for each cronjob. Then you can safely add, remove or update specific cronjobs without worrying about others.

Comment: Alternatively to this, if the jobs just need to run hourly/daily/weekly/monthly, you can just drop scripts in `/etc/cron.{hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}` or `/etc/periodic/{hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}` (depending on which the system has).

Answer (score 4):

You can use serie of command to accomplish this. Here is sample script to do it:

```
#get current cron
crontab -l >cron_c
#add new lines
echo "0 * * * * command" >>cron_c
#remove duplicates
sort -u cron_c >cron_n
#install new cron
crontab cron_n
```

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned Ubuntu in the tags, so I would suggest using `systemd` with generic user services. The advantage being that enabling a service several times will have no effect it is already enabled.

**1. Create generic user services**

For e.g. `X` create `X.service` in `/usr/lib/systemd/user`

```
[Unit]
Description=X service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/X.e
```

And a matching `X.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for X

[Timer]
#Run on workdays at 10 AM
OnCalendar=Mon..Fri *-*-* 10:00:00
#mimic anacron:
Persistent=true
Unit=X

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Same for `Y` and `Z`

**2. Enabling**

Use lingering so that services are also run if the user is not logged in, just like expected when using `cron`. Then enable service and timers. All can be done with `root` priviledges:

```
loginctl enable-linger john jack jill
for user in john jack jill ; do
   systemctl --user -M ${user}@ enable X X.timer
   systemctl --user -M ${user}@ start X.timer
done
```

Or if every user must have this, use `--global`-enabling of a service/timer.

Answer (score 3):

Add lines like this to your original crontab:

```
#INCLUDE my.cron
#INCLUDE my.other.cron
```

Have your `setup.sh` parse it, and do the obvious replacement. Optimise by taking no action if there are no such lines in the existing file.

Those are just comments to cron and will do no harm in the initial file. This retains such position-sensitive items as environment directives and comments, and allows for multiple add-on files, and permits them to be kept in order. You could even inject a timestamped comment with the insertion.

Answer (score 2):

If your script is always producing exactly the same lines, then you can `sort -u` as @Romeo Nino suggested.

A slightly different approach would be to tag the lines created by your script:

```
crontab -l | grep -v '#-- tag from your script' > cron.tmp
echo "0 * * * * command  #-- tag from your script" >> cron.tmp
crontab cron.tmp
rm cron.tmp
```

In this way, is you change the crontab lines in your script a bit (say change the start time), the old lines get deleted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The provisioning tool Ansible has [a builtin module for managing crontabs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/cron_module.html) which takes the following approach:

> When crontab jobs are managed: the module includes one line with the description of the crontab entry `"#Ansible: <name>"` corresponding to the “name” passed to the module, which is used by future ansible/module calls to find/check the state.

Looking into [the implementation](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/73dde45f0f7fc87ccaa849e9de69d88120be7d2f/lib/ansible/modules/cron.py), the general approach is roughly equivalent to this:

1. Construct the marker comment and job definition
2. Create an empty working crontab file (or array of lines, in the Python implementation)
3. Read the current crontab, line by line
4. If the line being examined matches the relevant marker, output the comment and the new job definition, and skip the next line of the original file
5. Else, output the existing line unchanged
6. If at the end of the file the marker comment hasn't been found, append the marker comment and new job
7. If any changes were made, install the working file as the new crontab